# RPG400 - RPG Source Code compilation error - Data descriptions for file not found

Tags: compilation, rpg

My source code is referring to some Screen Names & DB tables. Sample declarations given below:

FSCRNNAME  CF  E                   WORKSTN
FDBNM1     IF  E     K             DISK

I'm using the MicroFocus Rumba editor for compiling and using the built-in Compile within the Rumba Editor "Work with Members using PDM" (option 14 - for compile).

While compiling, I'm getting the following errors:

Error Messages:
1) "DATA DESCRIPTIONS FOR FILE SCRNAME NOT FOUND"
2) "DATA DESCRIPTIONS FOR FILE DBNM1 NOT FOUND"
3) "External description not found for file specified as externally described. File ignored.

Has anyone have a solution for this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The libraries containing the files SCRNAME and DBNM1 have to be in the library list for the compile.

Sorry, I don't know Rumba so I don't know how you would set your library list. But it sounds like you might be using an emulator, so maybe you could use the ADDLIBLE command before you use option 14 to compile.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the compiler cannot find the video file.
If you compile interactively, before running 14 on the PDM make sure that the library containing the compiled video is listed.
to search for the full video type in command line
WRKOBJ SCRNNAME
if you find it, it means that it is in the library list
otherwise
WRKOBJ * ALL / SCRNNAME
to find all the libraries that contain it
When you have found the library you can add it to the library list.
ADDLIBLE libraryName will add it in the first position
EDTLIBL send allows you to edit it in the position you prefer.

If you compile in Batch make sure that the library containing the video file is in the library list associated with the job queue of your JOB

with F18 from PDM you can set the job queue to be associated with the compiled
WRKJOBQ to modify job queues, including build parameters.